# Deprecation warning message with import android.hardware.SensorListener library

Tags: java, android

I add to application

```
public class ShakeActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener
```

But I receive deprecation warning from eclipse when I write it. Is there any new library with any new Listener for making ShakeActivity? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) instead.  [SensorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I really like lazy people who never even heard of google. If you would only post your question on google, you would get the following answer:

> This interface is deprecated. Use SensorEventListener instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html

Comment: Hi Adel, thanks for the answer. I accepted Marvin's one because it was first. I never tried to ask in Google questions.There is any forum for it?

Comment: I didn't mean Google questions, I only meant you should Google what you want before asking here. Anyway, good to know you found an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use SensorEventListener instead